# How can I put a background image on a certain position on all pages?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, watermark

I want to have a background image on all pages of a document. I know about the watermark "trick", but that does not help in this case because a watermark image cannot be repositioned; it always covers the entire page. I want my background image to be on the left side only. The background image should not interfere with normal text editing.

How can I set such a background image in Word 2013?

Answer (score 3):

Word does not provide a native way to freely position background images, not even Word 2013. But you can work around that limitation by simply placing images in the header. Make sure to set the layout option to something different than "in line with text" and you can freely position the image on the page:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this really helped me out. I used it to generate a form template which uses a scanned document as the background, and then automatically fills it out using transparent text boxes that get completed using a series of VBA macros. Positioning the background form image was absolutely impossible without using this trick.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the watermark image as you normally would. You may want to set a certain size for the image, 100% for example.

On the Insert tab (in Word 2013), edit either the header or the footer (does not matter which). With the header/footer editor open, you should be able to click on the watermark and drag it wherever you want.